# Need to set the limits of input data

Tags: limit

Needing some help please with a project for a course that requires us to create a python program that has the user input 5 numbers (between 0 and 100), displays those numbers on the screen, then calculates and displays the sum of the numbers and average of those numbers. I have done pretty much everything except for having the program determine if the number is between 0 and 100 and if it isn't, prompt the user for a number within the range. Can anyone please help me with this last part. Here is the code I have at present.

```
print("please enter your 5 marks below")

#read 5 inputs

mark1 = int(input("enter mark 1: "))
mark2 = int(input("enter mark 2: "))
mark3 = int(input("enter mark 3: "))
mark4 = int(input("enter mark 4: "))
mark5 = int(input("enter mark 5: "))

#create array/list with five marks
marksList = [mark1, mark2, mark3, mark4, mark5]

#print the array/list
print(marksList)

#calculate the sum and average
sumOfMarks = sum(marksList)
averageOfMarks = sum(marksList)/5

#display results
print("The sum of your marks is: "+str(sumOfMarks))
print("The average of your marks is: "+str(averageOfMarks))
```

UPDATE: I have managed to figure it out using WHILE loops as below, however I am sure there is a much more efficient way of doing it by having just 1 input statement with a variable (say 'n') which loops through the numbers 1-5....any ideas on how to do that??

```
while True:
    mark1 = int(input("enter mark 1: "))
    if 0 < mark1 <100:
            break
    print('Please enter a number between 0 and 100')

while True:
    mark2 = int(input("enter mark 2: "))
    if 0 < mark2 <100:
        break
    print('Please enter a number between 0 and 100')

while True:
    mark3 = int(input("enter mark 3: "))
    if 0 < mark3 <100:
        break
    print('Please enter a number between 0 and 100')

while True:
    mark4 = int(input("enter mark 4: "))
    if 0 < mark4 <100:
        break
    print('Please enter a number between 0 and 100')

while True:
    mark5 = int(input("enter mark 5: "))
    if 0 < mark5 <100:
        break
    print('Please enter a number between 0 and 100')
```

Comment: UPDATE: I have managed to figure it out using WHILE loops as follows:

Comment: Make a function from the while loops, pass the parts that change (prompt) as a parameter (e.g. `def enter_mark(prompt):`, and replace the `break` with a `return`.

Comment: Also, you can put the condition in the while loop, as in start with `mark = -1` and add the condition to the while statement `while not 0 < mark < 100:`.